# Reduce javascript array with Underscore.js (or with pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of items in Javascript similar to the following:

```
var data =
[
{"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb8a58","date":"2000-10-05T13:21:30Z","value":  {"country":"United States"}},
{"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb983e","date":"2000-02-05T13:21:30Z","value":{"country":"Norway"}},
{"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5ddfefe","date":"2000-12-05T13:21:30Z","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
{"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5fe29d7","date":"2000-05-05T13:21:30Z","value":{"country":"United States"}},
{"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419751e8a14","date":"2000-05-05T18:15:30Z","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
{"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419753e20b6","date":"2000-12-05T18:15:30Z","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
{"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f34ad","date":"2000-06-05T18:15:30Z","value":{"country":"United States"}},
{"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f3e17","date":"2000-04-05T22:15:30Z","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
{"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a506082f","date":"2000-07-05T22:15:30Z","value":{"country":"United Kingdom"}},
{"id":"9366afb036bf8b63c9f45379bbe29509","date":"2000-11-05T22:15:30Z","value":{"country":"United Kingdom"}}
];
```

I need to query (reduce) the array by the date. Either greater than or less than a pre-determined date eg. current date.

I was thinking of using Underscores reduce method to do this. Can anybody provide an example of how I could do this?

Edit: I trying something like this:

```
var itemsByDate = _(items).reduce(function(memo, item) {
memo[item.date] = memo[item.date] || [];
memo[item.date].push(item);
return memo;
}, {});

console.log((JSON.stringify(itemsByDate["2000-11-05T22:15:30Z"])));​
```

But this looks for an exact match and will probably not deal with the dates properly because they are strings.

Regards,

Carlskii

Comment: What do you want? Either *filter* the array to get a subarray for a condition, or *reduce* it to a single value (which can be a complex object)

Comment: What you have done can be easier achieved with the `groupBy` function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cM87e/)). However, I did not really understand what you meant with that fuzzy reduction ("*greater or less than date*")?

Comment: I need to create some charts from the data so I was going to break it up into subarrays by time periods. e.g. 30,60,90,120... days from today. Since the current date will be used as the start date for the query, I guess I only need to be concerned with creating a subarray for each period.

e.g. 
Subarray 1 - contains items with current date + 30 days
Subarray 2 - contains items with current date + 60 days...etc..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the set, you can do this:

```
var reduced = data.filter(function(obj) {
    var date = +(new Date(obj.date));
    return date < someDate || date > someOtherDate
});
```

If you wanted to reduce it to a pair of sets, you can do this:

```
var now = Date.now();

var reduced = data.reduce(function(ret, obj) {
    var date = +(new Date(obj.date));
    if (date < now)
        ret.before.push(obj);
    else
        ret.onOrAfter.push(obj);
    return ret;
}, {before:[], onOrAfter:[]});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback here. I think I need your second example because that appears to enable me to break the data down into sub arrays based on the date ranges. I'm probably doing something stupid but I get Type error on this line:  ret.onOrAfter.push(obj);
                     TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Comment: @user1513388: I forgot to change the function name from `filter` to `reduce`. I'll update.

Comment: Arh - Nice one! Thanks that worked perfectly! I'm assuming that since this is using the JavaScript date functions providing the date can be parsed it does more than just a simple lexical string match on the dates?

Comment: @user1513388: Yes, it is converting the strings to Date objects, then converting to a number *(ms since unix epoch)*.

Comment: Thanks one other thing! I was just trying a third (if else) option on the date e.g. "else if (date < now + 30);ret.thirtydays.push(obj);" but it's ignoring that line. Do I need to do something else with the "now" value in order to add 30 days to it?

Comment: @user1513388: The date is represented in milliseconds. So you'll need to calculate out 30 days: `var thirtyDays = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;` then add that `else if (date < now + thirtyDays) {`

Comment: One other quick question - If I wanted to include a count value within each of the sets e.g. {before:{total:xxx, rows:[]}, onOrAfter:{total:xxx, rows:[]}}. What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: @user1513388 Is there some reason you want to maintain a manual count? Couldn't you just use the `.length` of the resulting Arrays? `result.onOrAfter.length`

Comment: ...in any case, you could use the object structure you describe in your comment, and just update the `total` property in the `if/else` statement. An easy way is to take advantage of the fact that `.push()` returns the new length. `ret.onOrAfter.total = ret.onOrAfter.push(obj);`

Comment: Arr - yes that makes much more sense! - Thanks